# confused on sass/scss variables mixing with text

Tags: css, sass

trying to get my head around sass/scss and variables.

I'm trying to have a different URL path to images based on a theme light/dark.

So I have this variable setup:

```
$icon-url: "/templates/default/images/network-icons/";
```

I then want to do something like this to have it inside each different icon used:

```
background-image: url($icon-url+"twitter.svg");
```

That doesn't work, can't quite get it right, got any pointers?

Comment: That works for me. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work like this:

```
// import
$icon-url: '/templates/default/images/network-icons/';

// declaration
.foo {
  background-image: url('#{$icon-url}twitter.svg');
}
```

which results in compiled CSS:

```css
.foo {
  background-image: url("/templates/default/images/network-icons/twitter.svg");
}
```

The key here is the `#{variable}` which replaces the variable with the assigned value to the variable. Read more about [interpolation in the Sass documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation).

Comment: Okay, thanks. However, the app I'm using to compile and condense it, claims $icon-url doesn't exist which is setup inside a :root { section at the top of the file?

Comment: @NaughtySquid There's a different between `:root` and `$variable`. You should not assign variables inside your `:root` declaration. There you should only add CSS variables: `--foo: yellow;`.